# jq - order by value

Tags: json, jq

I have the following structure:

```
{"ID":"XX","guid":1}
{"ID":"YY","guid":2}
...
```

I have tried running:

```
jq 'sort_by(.guid)' conn.json
```

I however get an error:

```
Cannot index string with string "guid"
```

Please can you advise how I'd sort the file by guid and/or find the record where guid is the largest?

**UPDATE**

What I am actually looking for is the record where the GUID is the largest in the dataset. Thought sorting it would help me but it's proving to be very slow

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort_by` assumes its input is iterable, and expands it by applying `.[]` before sorting its members. You're providing a stream of objects to it, and each object expands to a stream of non-indexable values (`"XX", 1` etc.) in this case, thus `.guid` fails.

Slurp them to make it work, e.g:

```
jq -s 'sort_by(.guid)[]' conn.json
```

---

To extract the object with the largest GUID, you wouldn't sort the slurped input manually; for such tasks, jq has `max_by`, e.g:

```
jq -s 'max_by(.guid)' conn.json
```

and `reduce`, which is a more convenient construct for large inputs and eliminates the need for slurping.

```
jq 'reduce inputs as $in (input; if $in.guid > .guid then $in else . end)' conn.json
```