# Filter & sort array of objects then output only one property of each object

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, boolean, jq

I have JSON that dynamically comes to me in the format:

```
{
    "world": 583,
    "peace": [
        {
            "id": "Happy",
            "valid": true,
            "version": "9"
        },
        {
            "id": "Old",
            "valid": false,
            "version": "2020"
        },
        {
            "id": "New",
            "valid": true,
            "version": "2021"
        },
        {
            "id": "Year",
            "valid": true,
            "version": "5"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm ***brand new*** to [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), and I've read the tutorial and the manual, and several questions here on Stack Overflow, including:
[How to sort a json file by keys and values of those keys in jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331504/how-to-sort-a-json-file-by-keys-and-values-of-those-keys-in-jq)

I want to use `jq` to output all id's that are valid (`"valid"`=true) and have the output sorted by id.

So in this example, I would like the output to be:

```
Happy
New
Year
```

So far, I have:

`jq '..|.peace[]|select(.valid)|=sort_by(.id)'`

But that issues a *`Cannot index string with string "id"`* error.

How can I make this work?

Thank you, and Happy New Year!

Answer (score 2):

Keep the `.peace` array intact for filtering & sorting then break away from it:

```
jq --raw-output '.peace | map(select(.valid).id) | sort[]' <f.json>
                 ^        ^                        ^   ^
                 A        B                        C   D
```

Where:

- A: Keep array intact
- B: map + select = filter & keep `id` only
- C: sort result (which is a list of strings (i.e. ids))
- D: "spread" each item out of the array
- `--raw-output` will output as "text" and not as string, e.g. `Happy` instead of `"Happy"`

jq play fiddle available [here](https://jqplay.org/s/yfu8cs1A1W).

Acknowledgement: this answer has been vastly improved by @peak suggestion

Comment: I just ran what you graciously provided on a full dataset.  It worked a treat.  Thank you.  Now I need to study what you did for an hour to understand it completely.

Comment: Since the goal is to sort by .id it might be slightly more efficient to extract the ids first. As a fringe benefit, you get a shorter program: `jq -r '.peace | map(select(.valid).id) | sort[]'`

Comment: @peak Thanks. I didn’t know you could read immediately after select. Agreed this looks better indeed.

Comment: `select(.valid).id` is just short for `select(.valid) | .id`