# using jq how to sort array of object

Tags: jq

There is an array of json object, using jq how to check if an object exists if so returns the true else false

I tried this but getting error

```
cat fruits.json | jq '.fruits[]| sort_by(.version)'
```

I would like to sort by decending order and output the price of the most recent version.

```
{
    "fruits": [
        {
            "name": "banana",
            "color": "yellow",
            "price": 0.51,
           "version": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "banana",
            "color": "yellow",
            "price": 0.52,
            "version": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Doyou mean to check whether `version` attribute exists ?

Comment: Something like `cat fruits.json | jq '.fruits| sort_by(-.version) | first'`? Or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cat fruits.json | jq '.fruits | sort_by(-.version)[0].price'`

produces:

`0.52`

Answer (score 2):

You need try like:

```
.fruits |= sort_by(.version)
```

Example: https://jqplay.org/s/ntjioYhKWq

Reference [sort by keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331504/how-to-sort-a-json-file-by-keys-and-values-of-those-keys-in-jq)