# Use jq to convert object to sorted array

Tags: json, sorting, jq

I have the following JSON object.

```
{
  "1eba648810a9": {
    "ID": "1eba648810a9",
    "Tag": "1.0.237"
  },
  "2df272728204": {
    "ID": "2df272728204",
    "Tag": "1.0.243"
  },
  "2f5a63db6634": {
    "ID": "2f5a63db6634",
    "Tag": "1.0.179"
  },
  "91a86fec59b1": {
    "ID": "91a86fec59b1",
    "Tag": "1.0.202"
  },
  "9aa95de44891": {
    "ID": "9aa95de44891",
    "Tag": "1.0.189"
  },
  "a1caaccdba45": {
    "ID": "a1caaccdba45",
    "Tag": "1.0.183"
  },
  "a35ad9d93e62": {
    "ID": "a35ad9d93e62",
    "Tag": "1.0.42"
  },
  "a4e57f2db7eb": {
    "ID": "a4e57f2db7eb",
    "Tag": "1.0.181"
  },
  "d0254d6406e0": {
    "ID": "d0254d6406e0",
    "Tag": "1.0.253"
  },
  "ddeeb3d41a4c": {
    "ID": "ddeeb3d41a4c",
    "Tag": "1.0.177"
  },
  "f92356a49d78": {
    "ID": "f92356a49d78",
    "Tag": "1.0.178"
  }
}
```

How do I convert this into an array and sort it by `Tag`.  In the end I want something like this.

```
[
  {
    "ID": "ddeeb3d41a4c",
    "Tag": "1.0.177"
  },
  {
    "ID": "f92356a49d78",
    "Tag": "1.0.178"
  },
  {
    "ID": "2f5a63db6634",
    "Tag": "1.0.179"
  },
  {
    "ID": "a4e57f2db7eb",
    "Tag": "1.0.181"
  },
  {
    "ID": "a1caaccdba45",
    "Tag": "1.0.183"
  },
  {
    "ID": "9aa95de44891",
    "Tag": "1.0.189"
  },
  {
    "ID": "91a86fec59b1",
    "Tag": "1.0.202"
  },
  {
    "ID": "1eba648810a9",
    "Tag": "1.0.237"
  },
  {
    "ID": "2df272728204",
    "Tag": "1.0.243"
  },
  {
    "ID": "d0254d6406e0",
    "Tag": "1.0.253"
  },
  {
    "ID": "a35ad9d93e62",
    "Tag": "1.0.42"
  }
]
```

Note that the sorting by version is not entirely correct but that's a separate issue.  Ideally, I would like a solution using only `jq` instead of other external tools.

The [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70492898/using-jq-how-to-sort-array-of-object) has been suggested as a duplicate but it's not relevant because that is sorting an array, not an object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using jq how to sort array of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70492898/using-jq-how-to-sort-array-of-object)

Comment: That is sorting an array which is more straightforward than this.  This is an object so that approach won't work.  If I could just delete the keys I would end up with a stream or an array that I could sort but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You can select the values then sort that result

Comment: What do you mean by selecting values? The [`select()` function](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#select) selects values from an array based on some criteria.  What would the criteria be?  How do you select values from an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would convert the object into an array with [to_entries](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.7/#to_entries-from_entries-with_entries) and [map](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.7/#map-map_values)

```
echo "$your_object" | jq 'to_entries | map(.value)'
```

Sorting can then follow.

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over the (outer) object's items using `.[]`, and collect them into a new array by surrounding with `[…]`; or use `map(.)` with the same effect. The sorting can then be achieved using `sort_by(.Tag)`.

```bash
jq '[.[]] | sort_by(.Tag)' input.json
# or
jq 'map(.) | sort_by(.Tag)' input.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "ID": "ddeeb3d41a4c",
    "Tag": "1.0.177"
  },
  {
    "ID": "f92356a49d78",
    "Tag": "1.0.178"
  },
  {
    "ID": "2f5a63db6634",
    "Tag": "1.0.179"
  },
  {
    "ID": "a4e57f2db7eb",
    "Tag": "1.0.181"
  },
  {
    "ID": "a1caaccdba45",
    "Tag": "1.0.183"
  },
  {
    "ID": "9aa95de44891",
    "Tag": "1.0.189"
  },
  {
    "ID": "91a86fec59b1",
    "Tag": "1.0.202"
  },
  {
    "ID": "1eba648810a9",
    "Tag": "1.0.237"
  },
  {
    "ID": "2df272728204",
    "Tag": "1.0.243"
  },
  {
    "ID": "d0254d6406e0",
    "Tag": "1.0.253"
  },
  {
    "ID": "a35ad9d93e62",
    "Tag": "1.0.42"
  }
]
```